# SAVR. Is it even possible to reduce environmental EM radiation without using Faraday cage?

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, shielding, radiation, emi-filtering

Recently I saw a product called [SAVR Radiation Reducer](http://www.savr2u.com) in the market by [PowerLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPK0g.jpg) claiming the followings:

> SAVR Radiation Reducer basically scans and detects EMR waves and it
>   generates reverse signals to neutralize and reduce low, intermediate &
>   high-frequency electro-magnetic radiation emitted by computer and
>   other surrounding devices. Apart from this action, it also filters EMR
>   waves and flushes it through the A/C power
>
> Significantly reduces EM radiation around your computer and other
>   devices on WiFi with a coverage area of 4 square meters*
>
> Eliminates over 95% low, intermediate and high-frequency EM radiation
>
> Radiation clearance range up to 1GHz

Basically you just power up the device and place somewhere near you, it will 'reduce' EM radiation around you automatically.

Attached photo is the demo of the product effectiveness 
[image: Demo Before]

**[Updated 4 Aug 16]: Attached photo**

My question is,

1. Reducing EM radiation? is it even possible this can be done without shielding myself inside a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage)?
2. Is it possible to scan & generates a 'reversed EM wave' to cancel off or reduce the current environmental EM waves?
3. If EMR really was reduced to 0 (shown in photo), why the mobile phone still have GSM signal?
4. If working range claimed up to 1GHz, most [GSM band](http://www.worldtimezone.com/gsm.html) and WIFI band is above 1GHz range (e.g: GSM above 1.8GHz, Wifi 2.4GHz & 5GHz), how reduction was able to archive ZERO (shown in photo)?

The product official info,
http://www.savr2u.com
http://www.powerlink.com.my/#sav
https://www.facebook.com/SAVR-Your-Smart-Radiation-Reduces-525916917552326
https://www.facebook.com/powerlink.my/

Comment: It is claiming to work similarly to the acoustic noise cancelers. So *even if* it is not a scam, it can work in the immediate proximity of the device itself. So it is pretty useless, and seems like a scam anyway.

Comment: We could sick Dave Jones onto this.  At best, this device is a line filter with a display for improved placebo effect.

Comment: It would make quite a good paperweight. I wish I could get money for things like this from technological pre-schoolers.

Comment: Don't believe that a Faraday cage confers safety: my microwave oven is a Faraday cage, but with an oscillator inside...

Comment: Scam. A picture of an uncalibrated box labeled "Radiation Detector" (whatever that is) that does not show the actual spectrum nor the power level is not at all convincing. A more convincing test setup would use a [Spectrum Analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_analyzer) to show the actual RF power spectrum at the antenna. Real instruments report real physical units, not unlabeled magic numbers.

Comment: A tin foil helmet is much cheaper and arguably more stylish, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

*This product might as well be filled with fu-fu dust for all the good it will do*.

**The website provides no details of operation or specific ranges covered**. It looks like a cheap watch you could buy anywhere for $10 USD. There are devices called 'jammers' that make broad-band noise that can include audio 'pings' as well as RF sweeps, but these toys cost thousands of US dollars.

They in no way substitute or emulate a Faraday cage, they simple garble sound and/or RF so that packet scanners get mostly useless data. Audio 'pings' can make a hidden microphones AGC (Automatic Gain Control) reset to minimum gain over and over again, hopefully frustrating someone listening in, but a professional spy would use many microphones, some with no AGC to confuse.

**This SAVR device is a gimmick**. It in no way substitutes for or emulates a Faraday cage. A Faraday cage is a real physical structure with defined shielding properties *that contains that which is to be protected* from incoming radiation and prevent outgoing radiation. The manufacture makes no claims about frequencies that are covered, or not covered. The advertisements consist mostly of marquee 'splash' words and phrases that collectively add up to nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I'll wager it's a passive common-mode filter, which will reduce conducted noise and noise radiated from the cable, despite the advertising mumbo-jumbo implying it's doing something active. Plus an LED-backlit display of 'something'.

The reference to 'dangers' of EM radiation puts it firmly in the scam camp as far as promotional strategy goes.

Comment: BTW, *if* it is working as claiming, it will effectively jam any wireless devices around :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Q: Will it affect the signal strength of mobile phone or WiFi? A: No, it will not in any way weaken or affect the signal strength of mobile phone or WiFi. If it was really working as it implies, it would have to be approved as an intentional radiator of "danger(ous)" EM.